# MATLAB Accumarray weighted mean

Tags: matlab, average, mean, accumarray

So I am currently using 'accumarray' to find the averages of a range of numbers wich correspond to matching ID's. Ex Input:

```
ID----Value
1     215
1     336
1     123
2     111
2     246
2     851
```

My current code finds the unweighted average of the above values, using the ID as the 'seperator' so that I don't get the average for all of the values together as one number, but rather seperate results for just values which have corresponding ID's.
EX Output:

```
ID----Value
1     224.66
2     402.66
```

To achieve this I am using this code:

```
[ID, ~, Groups] = unique(StarData2(:,1),'stable');
app = accumarray(Groups, StarData2(:,2), [], @mean);
```

With StarData2 being the input of the function. This is working perfectly for my purposes until now, I need to know if accumarray can be made to give me a weighted average, such that each point in app (before the average is found) can be assigned a weight or that the @mean can be replaced with a function that can achieve this. The new input will look like this:

```
ID----Value----Weight
1     215     12
1     336     17
1     123     11
2     111     6
2     246     20
2     851     18
```

The new code must do the sum(val(i)*weight(i))/sum(weight) instead of just the standard mean. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the row index as the "vals" ([second input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#inputarg_val) to [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)) and define your own function that does the weighted mean on group of the data:

```
Weights = data(:,3); Vals = data(:,2); % pick your columns here
WeightedMeanFcn = @(ii) sum(Vals(ii).*Weights(ii))/sum(Weights(ii));
wmeans = accumarray(Groups, 1:numel(Groups), [], WeightedMeanFcn)
```

---

**Demonstration**

Starting with `data` (the new input with your weights) and your `unique` command:

```
data = [1,215,12; 1,336,17; 1,123,11; 2,111,6; 2,246,20; 2,851,18];
[ID, ~, Groups] = unique(data(:,1),'stable');
```

The `accumarray` usage is as follows (redefine `WeightedMeanFcn` *every time* you change `data`!):

```
>> Weights = data(:,3); Vals = data(:,2); % pick your columns here
>> WeightedMeanFcn = @(ii) sum(Vals(ii).*Weights(ii))/sum(Weights(ii));
>> app = accumarray(Groups, 1:numel(Groups), [], WeightedMeanFcn)
app =
  241.1250
  475.0909
```

Checking manually, with the first group:

```
ig = 1;
sum(data(Groups==ig,2).*data(Groups==ig,3))/sum(data(Groups==ig,3))
ans =
  241.1250
```

Comment: NOTE: `data` is not an input to `WeightedMeanFcn`. It must be defined _before_ defining `WeightedMeanFcn`! Then it will be [captured by the anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/applications-of-function-handles.html#brj5sua-1).

Comment: This is good but I'm getting output that is wrong, So I am updating the OP to show the exact style of the input and output.

Comment: @ImmortalxR `WeightedMeanFcn = @(x) sum(StarData4(x,5).*StarData4(x,6))/sum(StarData4(x,6))`. I'm modifying my code so the weights and values are more explict, rather than columns.

Comment: Amazing! that works great. I tried making similar changes myself but it wasnt working, but this is great!

Comment: @ImmortalxR Great! Just make a note of what I said about having to redifine the anonymous function every time the data array is changed, since the function stores the `data` array internally when it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `accumarray`, you can directly compute a weighted mean, or many other functions, quite easily:

```
nIDs = length(unique(ID));
WeightedMean = zeros(nIDs, 1);

for ii = 1:nIDs
    iID = (ID == ii);
    WeightedMean(ii) = (Value(iID)' * Weight(iID)) / sum(Weight(iID));
end
```

Is there a specific reason you wish to do this through `accumarray`?

Answer (score 1):

@Naveh - Generally, it is advised to avoid using loops in Matlab.
Specifically, if you have a large set of data with many groups - it can be very slow.

Using `accumarray`is the way to go, but defining a function of the indices, as suggested by @chappjc, is error-prone, since in order to be be captured by the anonymous function, you must make sure that

> data is not an input to WeightedMeanFcn. It must be defined before
>   defining WeightedMeanFcn,

as @chappjc says in his comment.

A slight modification to overcome this problem is to use `accumarray` twice:

```
Weights = data(:,3); Vals = data(:,2); % pick your columns here    
app = accumarray(Groups, Weights.*vals, [], @mean)./accumarray(Groups, Weights, [], @mean);
```

Sometimes you may need to replace the `[]` argument by the size of the required output.

Comment: Just one suggestion: use `@sum` instead of `@mean`.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to compute is not a weighted mean, but rather a weighted histogram.
There is a mex implementation of weighted histogram that can be found [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#whist). Though, `accumarray` is the safe way to go about.